# Why doesn't Option::map take ownership in a linked list implementation of Iterator::next?

Tags: reference, rust, closures, ownership-semantics

I'm trying to follow along [Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](http://cglab.ca/~abeinges/blah/too-many-lists/book/README.html).

```
type Link<T> = Option<Box<Node<T>>>;

pub struct List<T> {
    head: Link<T>,
}

struct Node<T> {
    elem: T,
    next: Link<T>,
}

pub struct Iter<T> {
    next: Option<&Node<T>>,
}
```

When [implementing a `iter`](http://cglab.ca/~abeinges/blah/too-many-lists/book/second-iter.html),

```
impl<'a, T> Iterator for Iter<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.next.map(|node| {
            self.next = node.next.as_ref().map(|node| &**node);
            &node.elem
        })
    }
}
```

In the `next` method, `map` takes an `Option` by value so it would need to
take `self.next` which happens to be of type `Option<&Node<T>>` by value. Wouldn't that "steal" the value?

Since the closure is a mutating one, shouldn't it need complete access to `self` and this code shouldn't compile? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Keep reading. The entire purpose of the code you are looking at is to present *many errors that you might see anyway*. The code you have pasted doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 1):

> Wouldn't that "steal" the value?

It would, except that `Option<&T>` is copyable. Thus `self` keeps one copy and `map` gets another.

> need complete access to `self`

Since the value is copied into the `map`, there's no connection to the one in `self`. Thus the value in `self` can be replaced inside the closure.